# Clear stale entries from Cache in Volley-Android

Tags: android, android-volley

I am trying to clear all the stale entries from Cache. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24464610/how-to-clear-the-volley-cache-automatically) link. In this link all the cache is cleared. I want to delete only the expired one.

I am using following Cache key: **URL + post params**

**Is there anyway we can enumerate over all the cached entries, check validity and delete them?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up extending Cache interface to provide me list of keys. I have posted the full solution [here](http://blog.ashwanik.in/2015/04/delete-expired-cached-entries-of-volley.html).