# How to clear volley cache of a url in Android

Tags: java, android, android-volley, lru

**Hello Guys**, I happen to have a project, in which i used the Volley library. I then discovered after volley gets the response from a url i tends to cache it. So all i want now is to clear the cache for the specific url.

I tried this:

```
    AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().remove(url);
```

and also this:

```
    AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().invalidate(url, true);
```

I got this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24464610/how-to-clear-the-volley-cache-automatically)

Thanks in anticipitation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear the volley cache automatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24464610/how-to-clear-the-volley-cache-automatically)

Comment: that looks correct, but have a look here on how to set it all up  -- http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: @Nick Fortescue ..... I tried that still it doesn't clear for a specific url

Comment: @Coded Phoenix In that case clarify your answer to say exactly what you did. Eg I tried doing both of the above, and it didn't clear the cache. I know this because ... (eg I looked in a debugger, or I monitored network activity)

Comment: i tried both, all to no avail. i checked the logcat for any errors, I found nothing but when i used: AppInstance.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().clear(); it cleared all the cache. And what i want is to clear for a specific url

Comment: have you got any solution @Coded Phoenix