# How to make a volley cache expire in exactly 1 minute

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm having problems with Volley caching. Is there any way I can delete the cache after one minute and make it request for new data?

**My Code**

```
    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
        (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        mTxtDisplay.setText("Response: " + response.toString());
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Comment: What problems are you having with Volley caching?

Comment: It caches items for such a long time that it refuses to fetch new items.

Comment: Do you get an error? I only ask because perhaps this is the problem that should be addressed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Volley, invalidate cache and make fresh request every (x) minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24495055/android-volley-invalidate-cache-and-make-fresh-request-every-x-minutes)

Comment: I don't want to invalidate the cache of the url but the the cache of the particular request.

Comment: Please edit your question to include exactly what it is you want to do. Be specific as to the goal you are trying to reach and the troubles you are having reaching it (i.e. errors, log messages, bugs, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do:

```
 JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
        (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        mTxtDisplay.setText("Response: " + response.toString());
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}){
 @Override
    protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        Response<JSONObject> resp = super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
        if(!resp.isSuccess()) {
            return resp;
        }
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Cache.Entry entry = resp.cacheEntry;
        if(entry == null) {
            entry = new Cache.Entry();
            entry.data = response.data;
            entry.responseHeaders = response.headers;
        }
        entry.ttl = now + 60 * 1000;  //keeps cache for 1 min

        return Response.success(resp.result, entry);
    }
};
```

this will keep you cache for the request always and only for 1 min

Comment: hi , i am using volley to set list to my recyclerview and setup pagination for LoadMoreItems() when i enable cache , onLoadMore items used to return append the already loaded items at the end of existing list , i fixed this by using                    Global.getInstance().shared().getRequestQueue().getCache().remove(url); but when i restart the app the it crashes since the adapter list.size is returned null , how can i make a fresh requset after removing cache ? please help

Comment: @KaustubhBhagwat Did you resolved the issue. I am facing same issue.