# Volley NetworkImageView clear cached image

Tags: android, android-volley

Does anybody know if it is possible to clear the cached image from a single NetworkImageView using Googles Volley library?

I have an avatar image in a NetworkImageView and would like to show the new image once I have uploaded it to the server. At the moment if I do
 `profileImg.setImageUrl("myUrl", mImageLoader);` I get the cached image.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230431/google-volley-when-to-use-cache-remove-and-cache-invalidate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to belatedly answer my own question. I ended up taking a different approach to ensure that I always get the latest copy of an avatar image and it turned out to be very simple.

Instead of trying to clear out an individual image from the cache I use the following method.

```
int time = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis());//gets the current time in milliseconds
String myUrl = "www.mySite.com?timestamp=" + String.ValueOf(time);
profileImg.setImageUrl("myUrl", mImageLoader);
```

What this does is to append an imaginary parameter to the url I call to get the image with a current timestamp. This guarantees that I am always making a call to a unique url and so therefore am always getting the most up-to-date version of that image.

The beauty of this approach is that it is not limited to Volley and can be used however you choose to make network calls.

Comment: That is hardly a solution. It means you are redownloading the image every time you want to display it, even if it hadn't changed since the last time you downloaded it.

Comment: It's a solution that works given the situation. Care to offer an alternative?

Comment: Sure. Just expose a method to remove keys from your image cache, with a twist: Volley stores keys as a combination of the width and height of the image, with the URL. So instead of removing the key string, you will have to remove any value whose key *contains* the URL.

Answer (score 5):

Check this out :

1) **Turning off cache :** 
    If you want disable the cache for a particular url, you can use setShouldCache() method as below.

```
StringRequest stringReq = new StringRequest(....);
stringReq.setShouldCache(false);
```

2) **Deleting cache for particular URL** : Use remove() to delete cache of an URL.

```
yourRequestQueue.getCache().remove(url);
```

3) **Deleting all the cache** :

```
yourRequestQueue.getCache().clear(url);
```

Also, check out this link [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: none of the above approach is working for network imageview. any idea?

Comment: Same case with me, nothing works, anybody found solution?

Comment: check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333351/disable-volley-cache-management.  Check the answer from "Versa"

Answer (score 1):

in the LruBitmapCache you should do diable put(url, bitmap) :

```
 @Override
    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
       // put(url, bitmap);
    }
```

by this way every time you call the volley method image don't save to catch

Answer (score 0):

```
  To turn off the cache:

1
request.setShouldCache(false);
to remove the cache for a specific request:

1
queue.getCache().remove(url);
to clear all cache:

1
queue.getCache().clear();
to invalidate the cache: this will allow to display the cached data until the response is received. When the response is received, it will automatically override the cached data.

1
queue.getCache().invalidate(url, true);

    for more details you can refer to the 
    url:http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2014/02/01/android-volley-tutorial/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create the cache like this:

```
RequestQueue requests = Volley.newRequestQueue( context );
BitmapCache cache = new BitmapCache(cacheSize);
ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader( requests, cache );
```

You can clear all like this:

```
public void clear () {
    cache.evictAll();
    requests.getCache().clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created volleySingleton Class. I load image from ImageLoader . I have a requirement of deleting the cache but  not able do that. Used all these three method

1) Deleting cache for particular URL : Use remove() to delete cache of an URL.

VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().remove(ImageUrl);
2) Deleting all the cache :

VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().clear();

3)
 VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().invalidate(ImageUrl,true);

I have tried all of them but cashe is not getting deleted