# Android volley multiple request. debug work fine, run app work wrong

Tags: android, android-volley

I have a problem when try to execute requests one after another without user participation.
When run app i can see this log

```
Posting params: {email=xxxxx@gmail.com, tag=getConnectors}
    verifyOperation onResponse --> 1 operation
    verifyOperation onResponse --> {"result":"85","msg":"ok, user register, your password is your number phone!"}                                                                                              
  response 1 operation is ok call -->getConnectors
Posting params: {email=xxxxx@gmail.com, tag=geinfodates}
verifyOperation onResponse --> 2 operation
verifyOperation onResponse -->{"result":"85","msg":"ok, user register, your password is your number phone!"}
```

But when debug app , the result for the 2 operation is correct:

```
Posting params: {email=xxxxx@gmail.com, tag=geinfodates}
verifyOperation onResponse --> 2
verifyOperation onResponse -->{"token":"xxxxxxxx"}
```

I have a singlenton class, where I have my StringRequest
with different types of listeners

```
 void verifyOperation(final HashMap paramOperation, final int opcion,final String url) {
            pref = new PrefManager(context);
            String urlFinale=url;
            StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                    urlFinale, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
 switch (opcion) {

                        case 1:
                           if (operation.result >= 0)
                           break;
                        case :2  .....
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(context,
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            HashMap<String, String> profile = new HashMap<>();
            Set set = paramOperation.entrySet();
            Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
            //String number=pref.getMobileNumber();
            String mail = pref.getMail();
            switch (opcion) {
                case 1:
                    break;
                case 2:
                    profile = pref.getUserDetails();
                 break;
}
```

and finally add my stringrequest to my singlenton class to control volley request

```
// Adding request to request queue
        MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);



public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
            req.setTag(TAG);
            req.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                    MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS,
                    -1, //intentos
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            getRequestQueue().add(req);
        }
```

I played with the default parameters RetryPolicy, but always fails.
I do not understand as the answer to my second request can be just the answer to the first, to call this second operation I need to go through the first onresponse.
The second call can never return the same data as the first, as seen in the log when I debug

Answer (score 0):

I don´t understand because some guy send me a negative vote...

I fixed my problem. Maybe can help my solution to someone.
Volley have a cache 
When you add a request to the queue, you can disable cache
https://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/volley/simple.html
For this reason when  I debug, my app work fine, the cache should was deleted for volley by time(1-2 second into requests) , and when I run my app the cache work and return always the first response.
You can disable the cache , this is a example
[Disable Volley cache management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333351/disable-volley-cache-management)