# Android Volley cache issues

Tags: java, android, android-studio, caching, android-volley

Attempting to load specific api through twitch headers. This Code has always worked in the past in fact still works but is pulling another user that i have replaced.

Tried to use android volley url to string, tried Variable
tried to clear cache in code, in app, and in device
this appears to be related to the volley's cache but i cant seem to clear it.

I dont feel it is api related otherwise wouldn't pull the old information either. or at least wouldn't work after cache was cleared.

```
// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    queue.getCache().clear();
    String url = "https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users?login=Twitchuser";


    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (com.android.volley.Request.Method.GET, url, null, new 
            Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {

                        JSONObject jsonObject = response;
                        JSONArray JA = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject object = JA.getJSONObject(i);
                            String bio = object.getString("description");
                            mTextView2.append(bio);
                        }

                        JSONObject jsonObject2 = response;
                        JSONArray JA2 = jsonObject2.getJSONArray("data");
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject object = JA2.getJSONObject(i);
                            String name = 
  object.getString("display_name");
                            mTextView.append(name);
                        }

                        JSONObject jsonObject3 = response;
                        JSONArray JA3 = jsonObject3.getJSONArray("data");
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject object = JA3.getJSONObject(i);
                            String Image =                
                          object.getString("profile_image_url");
                            new 
        DownLoadImageTask(mImageView).execute(Image);
                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }


            }


                    , new Response.ErrorListener()


            {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    mTextView.append("Welcome Guest");
                    Log.e("VOLLEY", "ERROR");

                }
            })


    {    //this is the part, that adds the header to the request

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Client-ID", "Client id");
            params.put("content-type", "application/json");
            return params;
        }


    };

    MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
```

shoud get twitch user name, description and logo and display to card within the android app. it does, but for the old user entered.

Comment: Did you try to search for "disable volley cache"? [look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333351/disable-volley-cache-management)

Comment: tried invalidating Volley Cache and disabling cache no changes, 
Tried to invalidate android studio cache and restart same no luck.

Comment: I am not able to figure out what happened however work around i used is recreated the activity and java file and all runs smoothly again firmly believing i was doing something wrong when it comes to clearing the cache.