# Volley to get data everytime from SERVER not cache

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

How do I make volley fetch data (e.g. JSON) everytime from SERVER, not at all from previous cache.

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "https://example.com/example.json", null,
                response -> {
                    DataModel model = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), PrivacyModel.class);
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle("Data")
                            .setMessage(Model.getData())
                            .setPositiveButton("Okay", (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss())
                            .setIcon(R.drawable.status).show();
                },
                error -> // Show a toast
        requestQueue.add(request);
```

Comment: Show your code that isn't working.  How is the cache implemented?

Comment: I have added my code, I wan't to make sure whenever my above code is executed, volley doesn't search in cache, but fetch from server EVERYTIME.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25333872/13373270.

Comment: oh yeah, thank you, I get it now.. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to not use cache, I has to set

```
request.setShouldCache(false);
```

setShouldCache to false before making request.