# android app doesn't update unill i clear cache

Tags: java, android, android-studio, caching

I am new in android developing, I have developing app that fetch data from server and update the UI with it, my problem is that when i do change in the app it doesn't update the UI until I go to the app storage and clear cache
I don't know where is the problem in my code and who to solve it
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Kindly, show the code .

Comment: @KamalNayan thank you very much, I found the answer, the problem was in the new volley library that i use, it solved by using request.setShouldCache(false); before adding the request to the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank god I found it in this answer:
[Disable Volley cache management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333351/disable-volley-cache-management?answertab=votes#tab-top)
The problem was in my new volley library
I was changed my library from 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19' to 'dev.dworks.libs:volleyplus:0.1.4'
and it seemed that in the new one I should stop caching by my own by this commend

```
request.setShouldCache(false);
requestQueue.add(request);
```