# Preventing android volley from caching image

Tags: android, caching, networking, imageview, android-volley

i have Volley network ImageView , problem is when image is changed inside sever volley still uses cached image which is old one , is there anyway that volley understand that image changed inside server ? or if there is't , how can i prevent it from caching ?

here is my current code :

```
private void networkImage(){
    String url = "http://example.com/profilePictures/"+username+".jpg";

    networkImageView = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.IBProfilePicture);
    networkImageView.setOnClickListener(this);

    RequestQueue networkQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    networkQueue.getCache().remove(url);
    networkQueue.getCache().clear();
    ImageLoader networkImageLoader = new ImageLoader(networkQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
        @Override
        public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {

        }
    });

    networkImageView.setImageUrl(url,networkImageLoader);
}
```

Comment: recommand for add extra timestamp argument for user profile image url. Maybe you could check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25302006/188784

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. changes the server's cache strategy if you can.
2. you can use `request.setShouldCache(false)` to disable cache for a request.

for method 2 you can do that by overriding `ImageLoader.makeImageRequest()`;

```
public class NoCacheImageLoader extends ImageLoader {
    public NoCacheImageLoader(RequestQueue queue, ImageCache imageCache) {
        super(queue, imageCache);
    }

    @Override
    protected Request<Bitmap> makeImageRequest(String requestUrl, int maxWidth, int maxHeight, ImageView.ScaleType scaleType, String cacheKey) {
        Request<Bitmap> request =  super.makeImageRequest(requestUrl, maxWidth, maxHeight, scaleType, cacheKey);
        // key method
        request.setShouldCache(false);
        return request;
    }
}
```

then use `NoCacheImageLoader` instead of `ImageLoader`. Now it will not cache the image into disk.

by the way you should still add timestamp to the url, because if the urls are the same, the `NetworkImageView` will not load the image again.

Comment: so i guess there is no storage problem anymore ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution:

```
private void networkImage(){
    String url = "http://example.com/profilePictures/"+username+".jpg";

    networkImageView = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.IBProfilePicture);
    networkImageView.setOnClickListener(this);

    RequestQueue networkQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    ImageLoader networkImageLoader = new ImageLoader(networkQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
        @Override
        public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {

        }
    });

    networkImageView.setImageUrl(url+"?time="+System.currentTimeMillis(),networkImageLoader);
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly , but all of those cached images are going to fill the storage , aren't they ?

Comment: Yes, It make other store cache for your image. In your case only have profile picture updated, I think have no problem with storage.

Comment: First of all Thank you , is there any limit for cache ? I mean app will contain more than hundred users which can view each other's profile , if there is a limit for cache and it won't fill entire storage , I'm OK with that .